# gVim reg exp: How to search with saved pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I have some patterns like

```
a,10
a,12
a,13   
b,20
b,22    
c,30    
d,33
```

I want to convert to

```
a,10,12,13

b,20,22,0

c,30,0,0

d,33,0,0
```

using gVim regexp. 
Is it possible to search with saved patterns in gVim regular expression? Like

```
%s/\\(.\*\\),\\(.\*\\)\n\1..../\1,\2/gc
```

Or is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Convoluted but following would work

```
:%s/\v\d+$\zs\n\w+
:%s/\d\zs$/,0,0,0
:%s/\v^\w+(,\d+){3}\zs.*$
```

**`:%s/\v\d+$\zs\n\w+`**

- search all lines ending with a digit
- followed by a newline
- starting with a word
- and removes the newline and word

**`:%s/\d\zs$/,0,0,0`**

- Add three 0's to each line ending with a digit

**`:%s/\v^\w+(,\d+){3}\zs.*$`**

- Removes until the end line after the 3th matching comma/digit pair

Comment: hey Lieven, my question was wrongly edited by some moderator. i just updated [ no blank lines after all lines of a and then same for b and c] ...

Comment: @keerthankumar - you could do `0,$-1s/\v(\w+),\d+\n(\1)@!\zs/\r/ge
` as a first step